# ReplaceTest(int i) not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

```
public string ReplaceTest(int i)
{
    string rep = this.textBox3.Text;
    string reped = rep.Replace("sir, this.textBox3.Text");
}
```

Like this? this is what i want to do but another error comes up not all code paths return a value

Comment: First we must know is what you want to do. You want to replace "sir" with..?

Comment: You should provide two parameters - what to replace, and which string to use as replacement. Use IntelliSense

Comment: If you put the caret on the replace method and press F12 it'll show you the definitions of `Replace`. None of them take 1 argument.

Comment: `string reped = rep.Replace("sir", "with what?");`

Comment: to avoid heavy down voting on questions you should describe better your current situation, meaning to mention that you have an error and that the error message is ..[your error message]... Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Please stop changing your question for random changes breaking your code in different ways. Describe in words what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The error is pointing out that your method declares that it will return a string but your code does not return anything.  Add `return reped;` before that last brace.

Answer (score 3):

[`string.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) takes two arguments:

- the string *to* replace
- the string to use instead

If you want to *remove* `"sir"`, it means to replace it with an *empty string*:

```
string reped = rep.Replace("sir", string.Empty);
```

Comment: no I want to keep sir

Comment: @Mega1137Gamez so it maybe helpful if you edit your question and tell us what you are trying to achieve. Why do you call `Replace` if you want to keep it? Do you mean to replace everything _but_ "sir"? Please edit your question and provide an appropriate problem statement.

Comment: @Mega1137Gamez Then you don't want `string.Replace()`. That's used to replace instances of your first argument with your second argument. What ARE you trying to do?